# Не могу запустить certbot

Tags: linux, letsencrypt

При запуске `certbot` пишет такую ошибку:

> "Failed to find executable wervice in PATH:
>   /home/jerryko/bin:/home/jerryko/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/sbin/service
>
> Unable to find post-hook command wervice in the PATH. (PATH is
>   /home/jerryko/bin:/home/jerryko/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/sbin/service)
>   "

что такое `WERVICE` и где его искать?

Comment: Покажите что вы вводили, кажется мне это опечатка простая, должно быть слово service.

Comment: подразумевался явно *service* (именно прописными буквами — в unix регистр имеет значение).

Comment: Я вот тоже удивлен, но он мне упорно выдает wervice.
Я писал certbot register --email и т.д.

Comment: гм. wervice = web service?

Comment: Починил )
В /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini была написана строчка "post-hook = wervice nginx reload" вместо "post-hook = service nginx reload"